# Command.Parameters & Apostrophe

Tags: ado.net

This is driving me crackers!  Think I've tried everything and just can't figure out whats going on. To make matters worse, I don't have access to SQL Profiler on the SQL server.

The test value being sent to the method is 'Barrhead Townswomen''s Guild Collection'

As you an see, I'm using a replace to change a single apostrophe to a double. I'm thinking this is somehow messing up the SQL!

My query is not returning any results when I pipe the value into a command parameter. But if I just include the variable straight into the query, it works.

Here is the query (its been stripped down for brevity):

```
public DataTable select_advancedSearch(string collection)
        {
        string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connname].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;
                SQL = "SELECT tbl1.ResourceID, tbl1.ItemTitle, tbl1.Type, tbl1.Description, tbl1.CollectionTitle ";
                SQL += "FROM [ercHeritage].[dbo].[ERC_HERITAGE_CORE] tbl1 ";
                SQL += "WHERE tbl1.CollectionTitle LIKE '%'+ @Input1 +'%' ";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Input1", SqlDbType.NVarChar,255);
                    command.Parameters["@Input1"].Value =  collection.Replace("'", "''").Trim();
                    DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter MyAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        MyAdaptor.SelectCommand = command;
                        MyAdaptor.Fill(MyTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("There was a problem with your request.");
                    }
                    return MyTable;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any answers appreciated!

Thanks Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to escape apostrophes in a parameter value. You only do that if you include the string literal in the command text.